# Convert a integer into string MM:SS in Python

Tags: python

I wish to know if there is a way to convert the value of an integer into a sort of time-stamp, just as using `strftime("%H:%M", gmtime())` will output the current hour and minutes.

The snippet of the code I wish to fix looks like this:

```
#The full program includes an input system which makes this snippet run.
import time
initial_time = time.time()
print "It has been " + str(int(time.time()-initial_time)) + " since you said that."
```

Let's assume that when the program is run, the value of the integer is 596, which is approximately 9 minutes, 56 seconds. What I need the program to do is to output 09:56 instead of 596. If there is a way to do this, please let me know.

P.S. If there is a way to introduce `str(int(time.time()-initial_time))` to the string using the formatting operator `%`, let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=596))
Out[2]: '0:09:56'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=596))
'0:09:56'
```

Comment: Can the initial 0 (which I assume is for hours) be removed?

Answer (score 1):

timedelta is the way I'd go about this (as others have already suggested). But for the sake of completeness, I'll mention modulo arithmetic:

```
In [86]: import time

In [87]: initial_time = time.time()

In [88]: end_time = time.time()

In [89]: print "It has been %d:%d since you said that" %(int(end_time-initial_time)/60, int(end_time-initial_time)%60)
It has been 0:56 since you said that
```

Also, to address your PS:

```
In [90]: print "It has been", str(int(end_time-initial_time)/60) + ":" + str(int(end_time-initial_time)%60), "since you said that"
It has been 0:56 since you said that
```

Comment: Is there a way so the `str(int(end_time-initial_time)/60)` outputs 00 instead of 0?